# Adding Seach functionality in react app to search through csv data

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, rest

The attached .csv contains a list of data to create a food ordering application. The requirements of the product is as follows:

As a user, I am able to search for available/open restaurants by time and dates via a search function.

You’re required to use React.js to develop the frontend and Node.js for the backend. You’re also required to use a proper database to store your data and write a migration script to migrate data from .csv file into your database.

Csv file looks like this:
[image]

As per the above assignment I am able to create a database able to fetch this parsed csv data into my frontend in array form using axios which look's like this:

[image]

But wanted to get some idea or hint about **how my search function logic should look like** ?

Answer (score 0):

Your search input will get the restaurant name:

1. Get the operation hours and the off days based on that.
2. Get your day from your current datetime.
3. Check if the operation times occurs in the same
   datetime or not.
4. If yes, then check the day with your off days.
   Otherwise; It is unavailable.